# Stemming queries elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I've successfully implemented stemming for elasticsearch and thus when I search for "code" I hit upon "codes" and "coding" etc.

My problem arises when I try to make use of the "must_not" field in my queries. When I include "code" in the "must_not" field, it's fine and I still get my results as expected but when I search for "codes" I don't get back any results even though there are documents which have the word "codes" in them for sure.

My query is as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < exclude_words.length; i++)
{
  must_not.push({term:{text:exclude_words[i].toLowerCase()}});
}
query = {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "dis_max": {
        "queries": [
          {"match": {"text": term}},
          {"match": {"title": term}}
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": must_not
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I'm using the elasticsearch api for node.js to construct my queries and get results from elasticsearch.

I'm assuming I'm having this problem because of stemming and that "codes" is stored as "code" in the search index.

Is there a way to solve this without using an external algorithm to stem my queries as well? Or is there an elegant way to solve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update**

This is my analyzer:

```
{
 "settings": {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "stopword_analyzer": { 
        "type": "snowball", 
        "stopwords": ["a", "able", "about", "across", "after", "all",      "almost", "also", "am", "among", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "but", "by", "can", "cannot", "could", "dear", "did", "do", "does", "either", "else", "ever","every", "for", "from", "get", "got", "had", "has", "have", "he", "her", "hers", "him", "his", "how", "however", "i", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "its", "just", "least", "let", "like",  "may", "me", "might", "most", "must", "my", "neither", "no", "nor", "not", "of", "off", "often", "on", "only", "or", "other", "our", "own", "rather", "said", "say", "says", "she", "should", "since", "so", "some", "than", "that", "the", "their", "them", "then", "there", "these", "they", "this", "tis", "to", "too", "us", "wants", "was", "we", "were", "what", "when", "where", "which", "while", "who", "whom", "why", "will", "with", "would", "yet", "you", "your"]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The text field has the following mapping:

```
"text": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "stopword_analyzer"
  }
```

Comment: What's the mapping of the `text` field?

Comment: Updated the question with it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I include "code" in the "must_not" field, it's fine and I still get my results as expected

It's not about `must_not` it's about the `term` filter you use in `must_not`. The `term` filter will take your search text - "code" or "codes" or whatever - and it will use the exact value for filtering.

But, the analyzer you are using is **changing** the terms being indexed.
For example, if you want to index **"coding"** you actually will have (as terms in the inverted index) in the index **"code"**. Remember that `term` will actually search for exact values. So, if you search for "codes" it will not be found as the single term in your document is "code".

I suggest trying out `match` instead of `term` in the `must_not` part as that will use the analyzer at search time as well. Something like this:

```
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "text": "codes"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "text": "coding"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! works like a charm, thank you so much, you just saved me so much of work!!!